# Bug or My Stupidity

Tags: jquery, parent-child

Not sure if I've just missed something but this doesn't work:

```
$(this).children('td.threadtitle a').html('thread title');
```

However this does

```
$(this).children('td.threadtitle').children('a').html('thread title');
```

I'm just trying to understand why this is occuring. But is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector argument to `.children` is  a *filter*. `$(this).children('td.threadtitle a')` finds nodes which match the selector `td.threadtitle a` *and* are **direct** children of `this`. Assuming that your threadtitle `td`s are inside of `this`, and not above or equal to it, this situation will never happen.

I think that what you might really be looking for is a contextualized selector:

```
$('td.threadtitle a', this).html("Thread title")
```

which finds things that match that selector as long as they occur anywhere under `this`.

Comment: The only way $(this).children('td.threadtitle a') would work is if $(this) is <td class="threadtitle">.

Comment: I believe you are correct - the filter of `children` should not go another level down. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should work. Can you upload some code so we can see your html?
2. Just a note: If you want `children`, you should use `"td.threadtitle > a"`. Otherwhise it should be `find('a')`.